# Services get users email address

Tags: services

I am trying to do the following thing:

-> Authenticate a user against Drupal. 
-> Get all information about user (including email address!)

So far I have tried to use the Drupal module services for this. I created a new service 'system' and activated the resource 'login','index' and 'retrieve'. I create a new admin user 'servicesAdmin' and gave him all the permissions (on Drupal side) there are available for the 'Services' module.

I created this little standalone PHP script to test my new service. It basically does three things:

STEP1 Login of test user 'tom'. This returns everything about Tom, but NOT the email Address:

STEP2 Login of the user 'servicesAdmin'. This returns the necessary session name, session id etc.

STEP3 Retrieving all information about user 'tom'. And here is the problem: If user 'servicesAdmin' has full admin rights, STEP3 will return the email address, if not it will only return all the fields but NOT the email address?

What can I do get email address without making the user 'serviceAmdin' to be a full administrator?

Thanks, Uwe
Here is the code

```
$curl_options_post = array
(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "gzip,deflate",
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "login", // who am i
  CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0,      // timeout on connect
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 80,      // timeout on response
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
  CURLOPT_POST            =>true
);
$curl_options_get = array
(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "login"
  CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 80,
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10, 
  CURLOPT_POST     =>false
);
//STEP1: login - authenticating user against Drupal portal.
$data = array('username'=>'tom','password'=>'password');
$url = '/portal.localhost/services/system/user/login.json';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $curl_options_post);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$user_login= json_decode($curl_response);
$uid = $user_login->user->uid;


//STEP2: Login 'servicesAdmin'
$data = array('username'=>'servicesAdmin','password'=>'password2');
$url = 'http://portal.localhost/services/system/user/login.json';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $curl_options_post);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$admin_login= json_decode($curl_response);



//STEP3: Retrieve all information about user with '$uid'

$url = 'http://portal.localhost/services/system/user/'.$uid.'.json?parameters[field]=mail,uid';
$ch = curl_init($url); 

$header = array
(
  'Connection: keep-alive',
  'Keep-Alive: 10000',
  'Cookie:'.$admin_login->session_name . '=' . $admin_login->sessid
);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options_get);
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);

print_r (json_decode($curl_response));
```

The url in STEP1 is the way it is only for 'stackexchange' as it would allow me to save this post otherwise

I am not allowed to answer my own question (yet).
Anyway, here is the answer to my own question: The 'problem'? lies within the file services.module in line 751

```
function services_remove_user_data(&$account) 
{
  // Remove the users password from the account object.
  unset($account->pass);
  if (!user_access('administer users')) 
  {
    unset($account->mail);
    unset($account->init);
  }
  drupal_alter('services_account_object', $account);
}
```

This function gets called in user_resource.inc after the user objects got put together. From the code you can clearly see that 'mail' gets 'unset' if the call is not authenticated as 'administers users'.

Why? I can not explain, it seems random to me.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue and it's something that I was banging my head against the wall why an authenticated user can't see his own email!

Here's the solution:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_services_account_object_alter().
 */
function HOOK_services_account_object_alter(&$account) {
  $account->mail = db_query('SELECT mail FROM {users} WHERE uid = :uid', array(':uid' => $account->uid))->fetchField();;
}
```